# Is there a mongodb query to merge fields in a specific mongodb document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

So,suppose I have a document like :

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "capital": "Washington DC",
  "language": "English",
  "other": {
    "China": {
      "capital": "Shanghai",
      "language": "Chinese"
    },
    "Spain": {
      "capital": "Madrid",
      "language": "Spanish"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to return my document as:

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "capital": "Washington DC",
  "language": "English",
}
```

when I choose the country as "USA" but when I have the country set as "Spain", then I want my mongodb query to return the document as:

```
{
  "country": "Spain",
  "capital": "Madrid",
  "language": "Spanish",
}
```

The fields should merge in accordance with the country specified in the "other" field.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are nesting the `spain` and `china` under `other` key but the document structure you are looking from mongo query is a bit different than what you have in the document, store each country details as a separate entry in the collection then you'll be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
country = "Spain"

db.collection.aggregate([
   // Make a uniform structure (why do you have 'USA' and 'other'?)
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$other", { USA: { capital: "$capital", language: "$language" } }] } } },
   { $project: { countries: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         countries: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$countries",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", country] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: {
         newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
               { country: { $first: "$countries.k" } },
               { $first: "$countries.v" }]
         }
      }
   }
])
```